# FDTD simulation for beginners using matlab

Tags: rf, rfid, radiation, em

My previous posts are as follows:

1.[Mitigation of dead zones when applying circular polarized antenna](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/456448/mitigation-of-dead-zones-when-applying-circular-polarized-antenna/456481#456481)

2.[Standing waves modes inside a cavity resonator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458463/standing-waves-modes-inside-a-cavity-resonator?noredirect=1#comment1153229_458463)

3.[Visual understanding of EM fields within a rectangular metal container](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458428/visual-understanding-of-em-fields-within-a-rectangular-metal-container?noredirect=1#comment1153291_458428)

4.[Insight into cavity resonators](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458518/insight-into-cavity-resonators?noredirect=1#comment1153504_458518)

5.[Multimode cavity resonator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/459460/multimode-cavity-resonator/459504?noredirect=1#comment1156389_459504)

I came across an algorithm called Yee's algorithm that uses a finite-difference time-domain to allows me to simulate EM waves. This was exactly what I was looking for. I know there is an abundant source of info already on this platform and on google. However, this is still too complicated for me to understand. In addition, I would like to implement this algorithm using MatLab.

I also know from the previous post of open-source software tools available but once again I have no idea on where to even begin. Can anyone help with regards referring me to a absolute beginners textbook that include matlab code for me to try to gain some form of understanding on FDTD.

Comment: you are supposed to ask a question so that someone here can post an answer to your question ... please update you post with a clear, answerable question

Comment: @jsotola my original question was to ask for help explaining how FDTD works but after doing some research I realized it would be ridiculous for someone to answer that whole section in a single post. Hence I figured it would be more efficient for someone to refer me to a textbook.

Answer (score 1):

in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1420087053) book you can find Matlab implementations for FDTD. It specifically used for microstrip circuits but it might help you.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let me recommend [this](https://eecs.wsu.edu/%7Eschneidj/ufdtd/) (1) excellent book, targeted to students.

It comes with C examples, but the code is not that complex. What I love about this is that it starts with a barebone example in 1D, and scales up using PML, 2D, etc.

Best of luck!

(1) Understanding the Finite-Difference Time-Domain Method, John B. Schneider, [www.eecs.wsu.edu/~schneidj/ufdtd](http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/%7Eschneidj/ufdtd), 2010